What is the earliest example of an author using an apparent typo to indicate that the story does not actually take place in our world?
In Terry Pratchett's science fiction novel Strata, it becomes evident as the story progresses that, in spite of appearances, the main character Kin Arad is not from the Earth we know.  However, one of the first indications of this fact occurs when she repeats the aphorism, "Reme wasn't built in a day."  When I first read the book, I dismissed this as a typographical error—"Reme" instead of the usual "Rome"—and I know I was not alone.  This struck me as a very subtle and interesting way to first introduce the idea that the setting of the story is not the world we know (or the future of the world we know).
I have encountered similar instances a couple more times over the years, and it may be an idea that has been invented my multiple authors multiple times.  However, I am wondering if there is a known first instance of a fantasy or science fiction authors using this trick.  (Strata is from 1981, so rather late.)

Merged by OP's request: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14153/31394
